# Apple Watch Rotate Image

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there a way to rotate an image programmatically on the Apple Watch? The app I have must rotate on the watch, and doing it on the iPhone and sending it to the watch is not an acceptable alternative. With watchOS 2.0, coregraphics on the watch has the `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat())` function. I have used this on the iPhone to rotate an image like this:

```
self.theImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( CGFloat(secAngle) )
```

However, I cannot find the `.transform` equivalent on the watch side. I've searched online and all through the watch api documentation, and can't seem to find what I need. Sure would appreciate help.

Comment: No, watchOS does not support that. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073029/creating-progress-circle-as-wkinter‌​faceimage-in-watch-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073029/creating-progress-circle-as-wkinter%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bfaceimage-in-watch-app%20for%20alternative%20solutions.) for alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks Ron - I already use a series of layers and static images that I manually rotated, so I'm well versed in that. My storage is approaching the 20MB cache watch limit, and I was told as of Watch OS 2.0, this CGAffine function became available for the watch. I don't understand why Apple added the function, but no transform function to rotate images. It''s so frustrating to have such cache limits on developing apps and a limited set of tools in the api. Thanks for the confirmation that I can't do what I want/need to do for my app. :(